# XCFramework with static frameworks sub dependencies

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, xcframework, static-framework

I have a XCFramework which depends upon several static frameworks.

My XCFramework is built with BUILD_FOR_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION enabled.

The sub frameworks don't need to be accessible from outside the XCFramework.

When I try to compile my XCFramework in the client(host) app, I am getting en error in the XCFramework's .swiftinterface file saying `No such module 'FBSDKLoginKit'` (FBSDKLoginKit is one of the XCFramework sub frameworks)

What seems to be missing is the swiftinterface files for the dependent modules. For example, I am using FBSDKLoginKit but the swiftinterface is not there within the XCFramework.

For reference I'm compiling the the framework as follows:

```
xcodebuild archive -project "TestFrameowrk.xcodeproj" -scheme "TestFrameowrk" -sdk iphoneos -archivePath ~/Desktop/xcframework.arm SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild archive -project "TestFrameowrk.xcodeproj" -scheme "TestFrameowrk" -sdk iphonesimulator -archivePath ~/Desktop/xcframework.x86 SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework ~/Desktop/xcframework.x86.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/TestFrameowrk.framework  -framework ~/Desktop/xcframework.arm.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/TestFrameowrk.framework -output ~/Desktop/Framework.xcframework
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm trying to do something similar. Is the only way to add the dependency on the client-side?

Comment: I've had similar issues with static frameworks on xcode 12.4. The deps are being fulfilled via the clients podfile but it all only works with dynamic frameworks. static gives either the `No such module` error or it `Undefined symbol` at link time

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding other dependencies separately with your created XCFramework when you integrate with client project? Looks like, apple recommends to avoid using umbrella/nested frameworks with XCFramework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had same issue happening with alamofire dependency . so what happening is when you generate xcframeworks you have dependency with FBSDKLoginKit fine . But after generating frameworks your client want to use .you also have to mention dependency as FBSDKLoginKit with same version then this problem not happen . For me I solves after adding alamofire adding in client side.