# XCFramework with other 3rd party dependencies

Tags: ios, swift

### Problem

I am developing a Framework (let's name it `MyFramework`) which I want to use in a host iOS application. `MyFramework` depends on several other 3rd party libraries (`Alamofire`, `ZIPFoundation`, etc.) which I have added as Swift Package Manager dependencies in the `MyFramework` project.

After creating `MyFramework.xcframework` and adding it to the host iOS application, I get a compilation error saying `No such module 'Alamomfire'`. As suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62870132/xcframework-with-static-frameworks-sub-dependencies) I have added `Alamofire` as SPM dependency in the host iOS Application as well, which resolves the compilation error. But during runtime I get a console message saying `Class _TtC9Alamofire21CompositeEventMonitor is implemented in both <HOME>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DevSample-frwzbtlatwjedobzfossixhbtork/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework (0x10346eb98) and <HOME>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D17DA122-DB76-4447-B8FD-14FC8405A856/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F68CBE06-CC7F-40AA-ACA8-2210048CA495/DevSample.app/DevSample (0x102ed31f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

### Questions

Is this expected behavior? As mention in this [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/CreationGuidelines.html) creating Umbrella Frameworks is discouraged. How to get rid of those runtime warnings/errors then?

Comment: Xcframework is used usually when you have binary code with headers, so that wrapping it in a Xcframework you can include it in your target. You could try a normal framework (New:Project:Framework) as the container framework. To avoid "is implemented in both..", make sure that the transitive dependencies ARE NOT embedded in your container framework, but embedded on the app target only.

Comment: @SardorbekRuzmatov could you please provide a sample project or explain it a little bit in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

@Nominalista I have created a similar app-and-modules setup in this way: I created the app, and the framework within the same directory, and then I dragged this framework's .xcodeproj inside my app. Inside the framework, I have added Swift packages as Alamofire, ZIPFoundation. I can use either of these 2 transitive dependencies both from the framework itself, and the app target as well with a simple ie, "import Alamofire".

I am using Xcode 12.5 and I am explicitly adding Alamofire as Swift package both to the framework and the app, I am not getting "..is implemented in both..." warnings. So can I ask you how your project is being setup?