# Xcode12.4 - iOS Umbrella xcframework framework with xcframework sub projects

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks, xcframework

I want to have some XCFrameworks into an umbrella framework or umbrella xcframework using Xcode 12.4 for iOS. I tried all the approaches mentioned in these threads. However, I am not able to get it working for any of the swift classes in my client app.

Note that this works seamlessly with ObjC classes.

[Umbrella framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397746/umbrella-framework)

[XCFramework with static frameworks sub dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62870132/xcframework-with-static-frameworks-sub-dependencies)

**Approach 1 - Create .framework**

When I build a .framework by adding sub xcframeworks to copy framework build phase, I see that xcframework subprojects are extracted to static libraries ".a" files.
I import this .framework in my application which is ObjC + Swift, I get "No such modules" error for all the subprojects in all the swift classes which imports the umbrella framework

**Approach 2 - Create .xcframework**

When I create a .xcframework with all xcframework sub projects, I get No such module 'XXXX' error in x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface when I use the umbrella framework in the client app

**Note** that I am linking and embedding the umbrella / xcframework in client app.

**Another Thought**

Also, when I create a sample app with Xcode 12.4 and import the same umbrella framework/.xcframework, everything works fine. Is this something to do with the client app .xcodeproj created in older versions of XCode ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things to try:

1. Make sure to have `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION` set.
2. Link the sub frameworks statically. If you are including the other frameworks using CocoaPods, make sure you specify `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`.
3. In your source files where you use the sub-frameorks, write `@_implementationOnly import SomeFramework` .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. #3 --> In your source files where you use the sub-frameorks, write @_implementationOnly import SomeFramework -- worked for me. Got this solution from the developers of the third party SDKs

Comment: I think that method won't work if the imported framework also does imports by itself, because these import also need to be @_implementationOnly